# Слово «контра» (разг.)

Tags: выбор-слов

Вы что-нибудь слышали об этом слове? В речи школьников и студентов оно проскакивает повсеместно. Однако в интернете не удалось ничего найти в словарях, нет ни единого упоминания. Оно вообще есть в русском литературном языке? Меня лично оно выводит из себя (терпеть не могу, когда люди его употребляют).

P.S. Это слово означает *контрольная работа, проверочная работа*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из Толкового словаря русского школьного и студенческого жаргона (2005):

КОНТРА - контрольная работа (шк., студ.).

Чего выпендривается, поставила бы автоматом, я же ей все контры сдал, все лабы.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему описанию, это слово из школьного сленга. Подобные слова регулярно образуются и большинство из них остаётся только в рамках одного поколения. В мои школьные годы (закончил в 2003 г.) "контрой" называли игру "Counter-Strike" и ещё помнили значение "контрреволюционер". Приживётся ли новое значение "контры" покажет только время.

Comment: Да мы и сейчас так называем Counter-Strike.

Comment: Неужели контрой у вас не называли контрошку или контрольную работу? =(

Comment: @Tagirix нет, у нас слова "контра" по отношению к контрольной не использовали, "контрошку" тоже не припомню.

Comment: закончил школу в 87-м. во время учёбы использовал слово «контра» как в значении «контрреволюционер» (реже), так и в значении «контрольная» (чаще). упомянутой игры в те времена, естественно, не существовало.